# Blender 3 - How to enter walk mode?

Tags: camera

In the old blender I was able to toggle the camera walk mode with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

In the documentation it shows how it is done from the menu (View ‣ Navigation ‣ Walk Navigation), but I can't figure out the shortcut.

It says `Shift + AccentGrave` which I think is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd> but it does not work

Comment: Go to `Preferences` > `Keymap`> Search by Name: `walk` , and you will see the shortcut

Comment: Thx, I just tried it but there is no match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign shortcuts to every menu item by right clicking it and selecting "Assign Shortcut":

[image: Right Click on Walk Navigation @ View ‣ Navigation ‣ Walk Navigation]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell there is no such shortcut, at least since Blender 2.8

<kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>`</kbd> ('backtick' or 'accent grave') enables [*Walk/Fly Navigation*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html) for the selected camera.  How the camera behaves in Walk/Fly mode depends on the setting of Preferences → Navigation → Fly & Walk → View Navigation.  It is definitely *not* a toggle.

Comment: Why on earth did they removed it, I used that all the time. Guess I will need to downgrade to 2.8?

Comment: @Black They didn't, it just got changed. I recently had to acquaint myself with this new shortcut as well. Seems like this type of changes occurs with every major update.